# XMLHttpRequest.ResponseXML is Null

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access a simple XML document from my JavaScript code. But whenever I ry to find the reponseXML it always results in null. Here is my code for finding the responseXML:

```
    function loadXMLDoc(filename){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
        xhttp.send();
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }
```

... Copied directly from "http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp". Here is how I implemented it:

```
levelDataDoc = loadXMLDoc("worlds.xml");
```

... I triple checked that worlds.xml is in that directory. But when I console it.. It returns

```
NULL
```

If you must see... here is *worlds.xml*

```
<world>
<width>20</width>
<height>30</height>
<startingX>10</startingX>
<startingY>15</startingY>

<voxelElement1>
    <x>12</x>
    <y>7</y>
    <width>1</width>
    <height>1</height>
    <color>#ffffff</color>
    <imageUrl></imageUrl>
</voxelElemen1t>
</world>
```

Comment: You'll have to check the readyState to see if the ajax request has completed, it's async and you can't just return.

Comment: @adeneo — It isn't async. The third argument to `open` is `false`.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. Do you see any errors? Look at your developer tool's net tab. Do you see the request being made? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: @Quentin - oh, didn't notice, but good eyes. Then it **should** be async, synchronous ajax is never a very good idea.